# How to use variables in a equation using Perl

Tags: perl, math

I'm trying to use possible variables in a equation with Perl.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

$a = "yellow";

$b = "orange";

$c = "col1fl0ur";

$c = $a + $b;

print "$a + $b = $c \n";
```

I want to be able to state the value for each variable `$a`, `$b`, `$c`, then be able to say that

```
$a + $b = "col1fl0ur"
```

You may ask; whats the point? just print out `col1fl0ur`, butI want to be able to use many more variables as well, such as in this case:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w


###values###
$a = "yellow";

$b = "orange";

$c = "col1fl0ur";

$d = "derp";

$e = "oplo";

$f = "qwerty";


###defining the equation###
$c = $a + $b;

$d = $a + $c;

$f = $d + $c;


###Printing###
print "$a + $b = $c \n";
print "$a + $c = $d \n";
print "$d + $c = $f \n";
```

Comment: I read your explanation, and I still want to ask "what's the point?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help a lot if you explained your *real* problem, but something like this may help.

Note that you should *never* use `$a` and `$b` in live code as they are reserved variable names.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f) = qw( yellow orange col1fl0ur derp oplo qwerty );

### defining the equation ###

my %sum;
$sum{$a}{$b} = $c;
$sum{$a}{$c} = $d;
$sum{$d}{$c} = $f;

### Printing ###

for my $pair ([$a, $b], [$a, $c], [$d, $c]) {
  my ($p1, $p2) = @$pair;
  printf "%s + %s = %s\n", $p1, $p2, $sum{$p1}{$p2};
}
```

**output**

```
yellow + orange = col1fl0ur
yellow + col1fl0ur = derp
derp + col1fl0ur = qwerty
```

If you want `$b + $a` to be the same as `$a + $b` then you will have to say so explicitly. For example,

```
$sum{$a}{$b} = $c;
$sum{$b}{$a} = $c;
```

Comment: what did you mean by this `you should never use $a and $b in live code` ?

Comment: As I said, they are reserved variable names used by Perl internally and their values may be modified independently.

Comment: Got you. The `$a $b` used in `sort`

Answer (score 1):

you may use Overload pragma..
You can create a new package as follows:

```
package Tst;
use overload "+" => \&myadd;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $value = shift;
    return bless \$value => $class;
}

sub myadd {
    my ($x, $y) = @_;
    $x = ref($x) ? $$x : $x;
    $y = ref($y) ? $$y : $y;
    my $value = '';
    if ($x eq 'yellow' and $y eq 'orange'){
        $value = 'col1fl0ur';
    }
    return $value;
}
1
```

Then in your Main program, you can do the things you like:

```
use Tst;

my $a = Tst->new('yellow');
my $b = Tst->new('orange');

my $c = $a + $b;

say $c;
```

This prints out `col1fl0ur`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than assigning values to Perl variables (`$a, $b, $c`, etc.) you might consider creating a data structure that will suit your purposes (whatever they may be!?!). Borodin's answer takes a partial step in that direction.

This example takes that idea a bit farther: the terms in your "mathematical" system would not be linked to individual Perl variables; instead they would be components of a larger data structure.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %xs = (
    a => 'yellow',
    b => 'orange',
    c => 'col1fl0ur',
    d => 'foo',
    e => 'bar',
    f => 'fubb',
    g => 'blub',
);

$xs{'a + b'}         = $xs{c};
$xs{'a * c'}         = $xs{d};
$xs{'d / c'}         = $xs{f};
$xs{'a + b - d + f'} = $xs{g};

printf("%15s = %s\n", $_, $xs{$_}) for sort keys %xs;
```

Output:

```
              a = yellow
          a * c = foo
          a + b = col1fl0ur
  a + b - d + f = blub
              b = orange
              c = col1fl0ur
              d = foo
          d / c = fubb
              e = bar
              f = fubb
              g = blub
```